# Cross reference with binding of abstract classes

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 abstract classes

```
abstract class Element<E : Element<E, S>, S : Snapshot<S, E>> {

    var snapshot: S

    init {
        snapshot = ((this.javaClass.getGenericSuperclass() as 
            ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<S>).newInstance()
        snapshot.element = this
// This is solution        snapshot.element = this as E
    }
}


abstract class Snapshot<S : Snapshot<S, E>, E : Element<E, S>>{
    lateinit var element: E
}
```

I want to bind both by initialisation of `Element`

Each element has only one Snapshot and Snapshot can access Element

But by `snapshot.element = this` the compiler says

```
Type mismatch.
Required: E
Found: Element<E, S>
```

How can i solve it?
The equal code in Java works perfectly

Comment: Kotlin doesn't handle that well as You've noticed, I always ended up using wildcards in that case.

Comment: @Pawel, if there no possibilities to use it, then it is a big minus point for Kotlin. Thanks Java, Kotlin compability i can leave this special classes in Java and for other classes use kotlin. But it is bad solution.

Comment: @anatoli can you please post the Java code that you are using? When I use that code in Java (1:1) it isn't working with the same exception... so there must be some kind of difference already...

Comment: As you are already using an unchecked cast, so you may just as well want to use an unchecked cast also to assign the variable itself...

Comment: @Roland, this is it :) Thanks. I did not come to it by myself

Comment: @anatoli you will also need to change the 0 to a 1 or you will get recursive instantiation with stack overflow on this line `snapshot = ((this.javaClass.getGenericSuperclass() as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[1] as Class<S>).newInstance()`